# Updating rows from other rows in a huge table

Tags: mysql, update, subquery

I have a huge table with items

```
item-id | name | type | extra
```

Many of them are "old versions" of type 0.

I have to update the extra field in all new items (same item-id, but type > 0) with the extra data we have for the old version.

Since this is a very large table with millions of rows, I have to be very careful with joining the table with itself.

Basically I want to do this

```
update mytable t1 set extra = (select extra from mytable where t1.itemid = mytable.itemid and type=0) where type > 0;
```

But MySQL doesn't accept t1 in the sub-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently read an article that might help you, see: https://dzone.com/articles/specifying-target-tables-in-mysql

Still think a self join would be faster than a correlated sub-query. Especially on MySQL 5.5 and less, where these type of sub queries are badly optimized.

Self join like:

```
UPDATE mytable t1
  JOIN mytable t2
    ON t1.item-id = t2.item-id
SET t1.extra = t2.extra
WHERE t1.type > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I was on my phone when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a "bulk select/insert into" script using cursors, since you mentioned it's a pretty big table. I'd also set the commit frequency between 20-50k records with rollback logic.

Do you have experience creating these types of update scripts?

Comment: How would that look like with MySQL ?

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax is wrong
Try this:

```
Update TableName
Set columnName = Value
From TableName T1
```